# PHP mssql behaving weird with different statements

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I have the following code:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
$stmtForCounting = $stmt;
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
*table creation code*
}
```

So far it works, but when I add a bit to it so it looks like this:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
$stmtForCounting = $stmt;
while (sqlsrv_fetch($stmtForCounting)){
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
*table creation code*
}
```

The `$stmt` variable becomes empty. Using `sqlsrv_fetch($stmtForCounting)` shouldn't affect `$stmt`, right?

(The original code was longer but I stripped it down to this trying to isolate the problem.)

**Edit:** It is not *Empty* because `var_dump($stmt)` still says `resource(9, SQL Server Statement)` but the `while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){*more code*}` in the table creation section won't even run once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should `sqlsrv_fetch($stmtForCounting)` not affect `$stmt`? You're assigning the same resource to `$stmt` as well as to `$stmtForCounting`, and by while-looping over the resource, you're traversing the table to its end, which can be done just once.7

If you `var_dump` both, both will yield the same output (i.e., the same resource).

Perhaps to clarify: You open the resource by executing the query and initialize a variable `$stmt` which points to this resource. Afterwards, you initialize another variable, which contains a copy of `$stmt`, which points to the resource. True, both variables are independent, you can e.g. `unset` one and the other still points to the resource. But the point is, they're pointing to the same resource, hence, when you perform actions on them like fetching rows, the state of the resource is modified (it points to the next row), and this change takes place regardless whether you access the resource via `$stmt` or via another variable pointing to the same resource.

Comment: "same resource" = pointer to result set/current row. copying the statement object just copies that pointer, hence they both point at the same result set, which is depleted the first time around. - Ah, the comment has been deleted, so now the rest of us are talking to ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my first comment, I shouldn't have done it so here it is for anyone who looks at this post in the future: Shouldn't `$stmt = $stmtForCounting` result in 2 separate statement variables?

Answer (score 4):

It's behaving perfectly well.

Just copying the variable in that context does nothing really, it still points to the same resource, and that resource internally has a row pointer. When you fetch all of its rows the first time, you move that pointer to its last position and that's where it stays.

It should be possible to move the pointer back to the first position, but that probably requires you to make the resource 'Scrollable' via the 4th parameter to `sqlsrv_query()` (not really sure about that one).

Answer (score 1):

It will mess up your $stmt definetly, it is same resource, and you try to read all of it twice.

Answer (score -3):

try to use mssql query instead of sqlsrv query
take a look here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php

Comment: Deprecated. From the Introduction of that same section: `This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.` Also, you should at least explain _why_ you recommend this, with 'It's just what I know' not being sufficient. Still, that wouldn't answer the question posed.

Comment: I don't think that would solve anything and as you can read here: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx) mssql is no longer maintained nor supported by Microsoft

Comment: I assumed the server was linux, sorry

Comment: A very fair possiblity, but in order to keep up with SQL Server advances, a Linux user would have to acquire a compiled copy of `sqlsrv` anyway. If there are any reasons to prefer (continuing) using `mssql`, I'd be interested!

Comment: (I think sqlsrv is available for linux as of 2012) damn, always late with comments